# Rewriting a piece of C code without conditional statements or operators?

Tags: c

I was in a technical interview where the interviewer gave me a piece of code like this

```
  int a=1;
  a++;
  ...something..
  ...something.
  if(a==25)
   a=0;
```

he said me to rewrite this code without using switch,if else or ternary operator for the if condition. How it can be done?

Comment: Was `a` indeterminate like you've posted or was it initialized to something?

Comment: I am pretty sure the correct answer here is this cannot be done. Since `a` has an indeterminate value there is no way to write an equivalent statement. Or more precisely, `int a=<insert anything here>` is equally likely to produce the same results.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's quite simple actually:

```
a *= (a != 25);
```

This will multiply a by 0 if a is equal to 25, else it will multiply a by 1.

If you're also not allowed to test for equality then here is a fully arithmetic way:

```
unsigned int v = a - 25;

/* test for bits set and put result in lsb of v */
v |= v >> 16;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 1;

/* set a to a if lsb of v is 1, else set to 0 */
a *= v & 1;
```

Comment: +1 and yes it does answer the question; I'm just curious, underneath wouldn't it still have a branch? I'd say the syntax in the question is more readable.

Comment: @legends2k No, a branch occurs when there is multiple code pathways, this only has one (first a test, then a multiply). This does not include compiler optimizations of course, that could potentially decide that a branch is faster.

Comment: Well, on some [old] platforms the evaluation of `a != 25` might require branching, but this is not what the original question is about.

Comment: @AndreyT I added a version that should be branchless on any machine. Never said it was fast though.

Answer (score 11):

```
a != 25 || (a = 0);
```

This does not use "switch,if else or ternary operator"

Answer (score 8):

The question, as posed, gives *undefined behaviour* since you are using an uninitialised variable. Therefore you are free to write any code you like (so long as it compiles).

See C standard **6.3.2.1p2:**

> If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that
>   could have been declared with the register storage class (never had
>   its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared
>   with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior
>   to use), the behavior is undefined.

That, in my opinion, is the smart answer: although you would be wise to be graceful when answering a question in this way.

Comment: dude? where do you get it from that int isnt static storage class type?

Comment: and in addition the question was how to rewrite it, not even that it has to be compilable so -1

Comment: @Zaibis: Sure, but how do you re-write something that could have any outcome? If I saw this kind of question on an interview, that would be the first thing that I would think of - they want you to waste time analyzing the solution to a problem that is unsolvable. There are a lot of these kinds of questions on the GRE quantitative section, and if you do not learn to analyze them properly you will never score competitively. In an interview, the employer is judging your analytic skills - if I were the interviewer, I would never hire someone who didn't point out that `a` is uninitialized.

Comment: Note that the question was changed in the meantime to initialize the variable *a*!

Answer (score 6):

Remember that assignment is just an ordinary expression, and as such can be used as part of another expression. For example you could use the short-circuit logical and operator:

```
a == 25 && (a = 0);
```

You need to put parenthesis around the assignment because assignment has lower [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `&&` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting answer could be

```
for ( ; a == 25 ; ) {
    a = 0; break;
}
```

This does not use 'if-else', 'switch' or 'ternary operator'

Comment: I had a similar thought, but with while instead of for

Answer (score 0):

If the context implied is a counting loop where `a` always repeats the cycle `0..24`, then perhaps a mathematically more appealing solution would be

```
a = (a+1) % 25;
```

But this of course wouldn't work in a sitation where `a` can be anything, and it should *only* be reset in case of `a==25`, while something `a==26` should be left alone.

The interviewers might like it though, if you search for a "semantic" solution like that, and can explain when to use this.

Answer (score -2):

I think interviewer wanted you to use this line instead of `if`:

```
a %= 25;
```

Comment: That's not equivalent. If a is 26, this will set it to 1.

Comment: It depends on context - I think in this context it is implicitly assumed in question that `a` keeps always increasing starting from 0. If I were an interviewer, I would be happy with such an answer.